# counting number of possible outcomes - rolling die 7 times

Tags: combinatorics

A fair die is rolled 7 times. And I want to get combination of (1,1,2,2,3,4,5). How do I compute the number how many ways I can get this? I thought it would be $7\times 6 \times 5 \times 4\times1\times1\times 1$. But in solution from my friend I see $7\times 6 \times 5 \times  {4 \choose2}$.

Comment: Why is it being downvoted? Mind to explain? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select $2$ indices for $1$ out of 7, then $2$ indices for $2$ out of 5, then $1$ index for $3$ out of 3 and so on.
We get ${7 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1} = 1260$.
Your friend is correct!

Comment: thank you for writing it like this, it makes more sense now.